# CSS gets all screwed up in IE(like half of the CSS didn't get loaded)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a site that gets completely screwed up in IE, and I was wondering if anyone could help me track down what's wrong with it.

The page in question is http://eksai.com/testing/

When I open it in IE it's like half the CSS code didn't get loaded. Font colors are the same, there are no columns, etc. I've cut the CSS file to a minimum trying to figure out what's causing this...but I still can't get it to work right.

Can anyone help me figure out what's causing it?

here is the CSS file:

```
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}
a img{border:none}
@font-face{font-family:"agb";src:url("../fonts/b.eot");src:url("../fonts/b.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("../fonts/b.ttf") format("truetype")}
body, input,textarea,select,button{font:normal 16px "helvetica neue",helvetica,arial,sans-serif;line-height:24px}
h1{font:48px/60px "helvetica neue",helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-weight:normal;margin-bottom:20px}
h2{font-size:26px;line-height:30px;margin-bottom:5px;font-weight:bold}
h3{margin-bottom:5px;font-size:20px;line-height:25px;font-weight:normal;color:#3a3e42}
h4{font-weight:bold}
a{outline:0;text-decoration:none;color:#2d81c5}
html{background:#d5d8db url(../images/public/body.png) fixed;background:url(../images/public/body-gradient.png) repeat-x fixed,#d5d8db url(../images/public/body.png) fixed;color:#52585d;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased}
.wrapper{position:relative;width:1020px;margin:30px auto 100px;padding:0 2px}
.page{position:relative;background:#fff url(../images/public/page.png);-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);-o-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);margin-bottom:20px;min-height:400px}
.page:after{content:" ";position:absolute;bottom:-8px;left:-1px;width:1022px;height:8px;text-indent:-119988px;overflow:hidden;text-align:left;background-image:url('../images/public/page-shadow.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:0 0}
.platter-section{padding:20px 60px 0px 20px;}
.main-nav{height:74px;background:#fff;-moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 1px;-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 1px;-o-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 1px;box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 1px}
.main-nav .logo{position:absolute;top:18px;left:24px;display:block;width:152px;height:40px}
.main-nav .actions{position:absolute;top:20px;right:25px}

.hang{    background-image: url("../images/hang.png");     background-position: 0 0; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 284px; left: 180px; overflow: hidden;  position: absolute; text-align: left; text-indent: -119988px; top: -46px; width: 300px; }
.actions {z-index: 2;}




h1{font-size:60px;line-height:64px;margin:20px 0}
.alpha{float:left;width:474px; color:#ff0000;}
.beta{color:#fff000; border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); float: left; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 159px; position: relative; width: 300px;} 
.signup-section-full-width{clear:both;}
```

Comment: Probably isn't IE-compatible CSS. Can you post your CSS for us?

Comment: I'd love to help, but [according to WoT](http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/eksai.com), that website is highly unsafe, connected to force-install trojans and the like.

Comment: Your page renders identically in Chrome and IE9, I don't see the problem.

Comment: that's probably caused by installing a font, took that out so it's safe now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of the elements your applying styles to are HTML5 - IE8 and below don't recognize them as valid, block-level, or stylable.

For old versions of Firefox, you just need to do stuff like:

```
section, article {display:block;}
```

For old versions of IE, use this in the head:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you have a number of CSS errors.

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Feksai.com%2Ftesting%2Ffiles%2Fpublic.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

EDIT:

You're also using HTML5 elements, so you might want to include something like Modernizr, which will adapt HTML5 to downlevel browsers.

Comment: which elements are those? I want to first downgrade to the minimum working page just to get something that works

Comment: @Andrew - nav and section are both HTML5, and not supported by IE < 9, so you have to use a javascript adapter to make them work, such as Modernizr or html5shiv

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and below do not support CSS for unknown elements which you use in HTML5 by default (no fuzz in IE9 though).

But if you create a element of the same tagname with JS document.createElement, IE will magically become aware if those previously unknown elements. See here: http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/

So use a script which creates dummy elements of HTML5 and you can go on.
http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/